# Can't install Gimp in Ubuntu 16.04 due to missing dependencies

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, gimp

I'm getting below error when I run `apt install gimp`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.9.7~17-ubu16.04.2.2~ppa~9eb75cd) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.9.7~17-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (>= 2.9.7~17) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.9.7~17-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (> 1:0.3.21~16) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libmypaint (>= 1.4.0~7-u16.04.1~ppa~c196a86) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Edit**: I've ended up installing gimp from *Ubuntu Software*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 2):

You must uninstall **Gimp** and remove the external **Gimp** PPA from software sources.

```
$ sudo apt remove gimp
```

Then open **Software & Updates** and remove the PPA from *'Other Software'*.

After that, you can install a new clean instance of **Gimp**:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install gimp
```

Comment: `apt remove gimp` returns as error which is obvious ... `Package 'gimp' is not installed, so not removed`. I've removed the PPA from Other Software and I'm now getting the following error upon gimp install. `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: It seems you have problem with servers, try change it in 'Software & Updates'.

Comment: That didn't work. Tried both main server and local.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with BOINC Manager after an update a few weeks ago.  The general form of my solution will likely fix your problem.

I dug through the dependencies of the package I was trying to install, then looked for other packages that depended on an older version of the same packages.  That dependency (especially in the case where a newer version was listed as breaking the second package) prevented the installer from removing/upgrading the dependency, hence preventing installation of the desired package.

Fortunately, this kind of conflict in Ubuntu is likely to occur only in relatively uncommon packages or those that come from third party repositories, so it narrows the search.  In my case, I had to choose between `golly`, a Life simulator, and BOINC Manager, which depended on and were broken by different versions of a GTK support library.  I uninstalled `golly` and BOINC Manager installed and worked.

Find the conflicting library, and you'll find why GIMP won't install.

Comment: This almost only happens if you have added PPA-sources that requires other / higher versions that the normal Ubuntu sources.

Comment: Exactly -- which can include any source that isn't vetted by the community for your Ubuntu version.  In my case, it was because the BOINC repository maintainer(s) didn't check for backward compatibility with 14.04.  They upgraded a seldom-used library.

Comment: Then write in your answer that the problem occurs because of manual added PPAs, because `the general form` of your solution don't help anyone.

Comment: "Fortunately, this kind of conflict in Ubuntu is likely to occur only in relatively uncommon packages or those that come from third party repositories, so it narrows the search." -- already there, from the beginning.