# Installation of GIMP crashing on startup

Tags: fonts, gimp

My install of GIMP is suddenly crashing on startup.

The launcher window opens and runs through it's setup process, but the font is all messed up (see screenshot).

[image]

The same boxes show on the main GIMP window, which opens for a second, then closes.

I installed GIMP via `snap`, and when I try to open it via the terminal the following error is outputted:

```
kirk@masterblaster6:~$ gimp &
[1] 46505
kirk@masterblaster6:~$ /snap/gimp/281/usr/bin/gimp: Gimp-Widgets-WARNING: parse_iso_codes: error parsing '/build/gimp/parts/gimp/install/usr/share/xml/iso-codes/iso_639.xml': No such file or directory

Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object width does not accept value [60 402)
/snap/gimp/281/usr/bin/gimp: Gimp-Text-CRITICAL: gimp_font_factory_load_names: assertion 'fontset' failed
gimp_check_updates_callback: loading of https://gimp.org/gimp_versions.json failed: Operation not supported

(gimp:46505): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 10:37:03.236: gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple: assertion 'dest_width > 0' failed

(gimp:46505): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 10:37:03.236: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:46505): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 10:37:03.236: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:46505): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 10:37:03.236: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:46505): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 10:37:03.236: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:46505): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 10:37:03.236: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels_with_length: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:46505): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 10:37:03.236: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:46505): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 10:37:03.236: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:46505): GLib-ERROR **: 10:37:03.236: ../../../../glib/gmem.c:333: overflow allocating 18446744073709551615*18446744073709551615 bytes

(script-fu:46620): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: 10:37:03.370: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error

[1]+  Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) gimp
```

The only thing I can think of that I did recently that could have messed with my installation is I installed Google Fonts locally via [this script](https://gist.github.com/keeferrourke/d29bf364bd292c78cf774a5c37a791db), but other programs like Inkscape and OBS Studio are loading in the fonts without crashing no problem.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Did you try  `sudo apt-get check` to make sure there's no broken packages? How about starting it with `--no-fonts`? Also worth looking into [finding dependencies of executables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6242761/7665043) to make sure it's finding everything it needs even if `apt-get` says it's all installed.

Comment: What happens when you install it from the repositories and remove the snap version?

Comment: @l3l_aze - The output is of `sudo apt-get check` is:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Doesn't seem to be anything there, running it with `--no-fonts` results in the same problem. :/

Comment: @KGIII - I tried this too, but `snap` was the only installation I could get working. All the others were giving me errors like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/971683/cant-install-gimp-in-ubuntu-16-04-due-to-missing-dependencies and I wasn't able to solve them with the answers given.

Comment: How odd. I'm not sure I can help, but you might get more eyes on this if you edit your question to include more information - such as which version of Ubuntu you're using and what else you've tried.

Comment: @saricDen I installed gimp from snap and also used the fonts script on Focal Fossa and the good news is that the 2 work fine together. You may be able to fix your installation of gimp by 1. Closing gimp 2. Move the config files 3. Restart gimp. The best way to move the config files is to run the following: `mv -v ~/snap/gimp/ ~/snap/gimp_bak`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @andrew.46 I tried moving the config files as you suggested, but I'm still faced with the same problem :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I too faced the same issue.
running the following commands to clear fontcache from the system solved the issue for me.

**Commands:**

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
fc-cache -r
```

Turns out this is an [issue](https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager/issues/4826#issuecomment-649551574) with snap.

Comment: This totally worked for me, thanks so much you're a lifesaver :)